# WPF partial binding to specific control

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a wpf form. Which contains  labels and other controls.
Whole form has concrete dataSource. I want labels in this form have another biding. only labels

```
<Grid>

  <Label x:Name="label"/>
  <TextBOx />
  <Label x:Name="labe2"/>
  <TextBOx />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough. Do you mean to say that you bind your form's `DataContext` to some business object but still want to bind some of form elements (e.g. `TextBox`) to a different source? If so, you can always use `Binding`'s `Source`, `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` to make the binding source other than `DataContext`.